# how display all images from folder outside app folder in flask app

Tags: python, html, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask project where the user uploads an image or a PDF file and the images are stored in the "uploads/Image" folder and the name of the image is stored in the database and the PDF files are stored in the "uploads/PDF" folder, and the "uploads" folder is outside the folder The project and outside the "Static" folder, the files are stored successfully, but I cannot access the images and display them in the HTML file by their name

```
-app
 ---static
 ---templates
 ---views.py
 ---models.py
-config.py
-run.py
-uploads
 ---Image
 ---PDF
```

views.py

```py
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.abspath('uploads')
@app.route('/')
def home():
   user = get_current_user()
   path = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
   print(f'path: {path}')
   files = Files.query.all()
   return render_template('home.html', path=path, files=files, user=user)
```

home.html

```html
{% for file in files %} 
  <a href="{{ url_for('file_view', file_id=file.id) }}">
   <img src="{{ path }}/{{ file.file_type }}/{{ file.name }}" style="width: 200px" alt="{{ file.bio }}">            
  </a> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the HTML img src attribute is not properly referring to the image file location. Instead of {{ path }}/{{ file.file_type }}/{{ file.name }}, you should use {{ url_for('static', filename='Image/' + file.name) }} so that Flask can correctly generate the URL for the image files.

views.py

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'uploads')
@app.route('/')
def home():
   user = get_current_user()
   path = url_for('static', filename='')
   print(f'path: {path}')
   files = Files.query.all()
   return render_template('home.html', path=path, files=files, user=user)
```

home.html

```
{% for file in files %} 
  <a href="{{ url_for('file_view', file_id=file.id) }}">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='Image/' + file.name) }}" style="width: 200px" alt="{{ file.bio }}">            
  </a> 
{% endfor %}
```

This code should generate the correct URL for your images and allow them to be displayed in the HTML file.

I want it will be helpful to you.
Thanks.

Comment: uploads folder is outside static folder and app folder